# Вывести данные rgb input type="color"

Tags: php, html

Доброго времени суток.

При обработке средствами php input type="color"  получаю цвет в hex формате, к примеру, `#ffffff`. Интересно, а можно ли вывести в rgb, к примеру, `255,255,255,` и как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
$hex = "#ffffff";
list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($hex, "#%2x%2x%2x");
echo 'rgb(', $r, ',' , $g, ',' , $b, ')'; // rgb(255,255,255);
```

Только нужно проверять - полная запись (#990000) или укороченная (#900)

Comment: А разве input type="color" выдает укороченую?

Comment: @Sergalas, я в общем говорю, что такой вариант нужно учитывать.

Comment: Ну, вариант, предложенный вам, хорош, но вопрос имено в том, нет ли возможности обрабатывать именно сам инпут?
 
Не дополнительными перемеными, не функциями, а может, какими-то настройками. Ведь при настройке цвета в этом инпуте используеться имено rgb, а выводится hex.

Comment: @Sergalas, ких-то внутренних настроек, я [не обнаружил][1]. Хотя, не исключаю, что завтра-послезавтра они могут появится.

   [1]:http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.color.html

Comment: Понятно, спасибо большое, придется функцией обрабатовать.

Comment: @Sergalas, нашел у себя в коллекции еще одну аналогичную функцию. Работает быстрее, чем первый вариант.

    function hex2rgb($hexstr) {
        $int = hexdec($hexstr);
        return 'rgb(' . ( 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10)) . ',' . (0xFF & ($int >> 0x8)) . ',' . (0xFF & $int) . ')';
    }

Comment: Ну, в целом, я вам очень благодарен, правда, чтобы не плодить переменые, я это через функцию описал. Спасибо ещё раз, ответ принят.